# How to Write a Symfony 2.5 Plugin

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-plugins

I am new to symfony just a month before, i am given a task to **develop a symfony plugin**. Can any one please Guide me how to write a plugin ? Any latest tutorial supporting symfony 2.5.
 i searched a lot but found legacy version.
Please Guide me
Thanks A lot !

Comment: Plugin for IDE or a Bundle for SF2?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html#before-you-begin-create-the-bundle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically in Symfony2 naming convention you don't use word `plugin` but `Bundle`. `Plugin` word was used in Symfony 1.x - probably that's why you get legacy version results, try searching `Bundle`. There's a lot of stuff in net about it. Try [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/index.html), [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html) or [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PONJajuH8P4)

Comment: Great (Y) , I already know how to make a bundle in fact done little work on them. But didn't know about this difference !!!